# Why is this way of receiving multiple vars in PHP wrong?

Tags: php

I'm upgrading php, and this is erroring out on the test server (works ok on production):

```
if (![$userID, $activationIDref, $expiry] = user_id_lookup($mysqli, $aid))
{ 
    //rest of function
}
```

The error for that line is:

```
unexpected '='
```

I don't see what's wrong with that syntax? Is there something obvious I'm overlooking?

Comment: check PHP version on the test server.

Comment: It's 7.4 - why does that matter in this case please?

Comment: [Symmetric array destructuring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.symmetric-array-destructuring) came in PHP 7.1. Are you sure the test server is running the version you think it is?

Comment: You can see which versions it fails on here ~ https://3v4l.org/ad1WF. 5.4.0 - 5.4.45, 5.5.0 - 5.5.38, 5.6.0 - 5.6.40, 7.0.0 - 7.0.33 all throw the error you're seeing so your test server must be running one of those versions

Comment: Thanks Phil. I'd changed a handler in htaccess as some of my php files were displaying as text in the browser instead of being rendered: <IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule> - so it was loading php5.4. I've changed it back so it's loading php 7.4 now, and now have the rendering issue again, but at least I know why the above error was occuring. Weird thing is that my production server is running 5.5.38 and the error doesn't occur there.

Comment: _"Weird thing is that my production server is running 5.5.38 and the error doesn't occur there"_ - maybe the error just gets suppressed there. But the even weirder thing is that someone is still using PHP 5.x on a production system in 2021.

Comment: I honestly don't see the purpose of that `if`-statement?